# vue-router with parameter can't run deploy on netlify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuetify.js, netlify

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <h3>Home</h3>
</template>
```

Test1.vue

```
<template>
  <h3>TEst page {{symbol}}</h3>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
      return {
        symbol: this.$route.params.id
      }
    },
}
</script>
```

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/test/:id',
      component: Test1
    },
    {
      path: '/home',
      component: Home
    },
  ]
})
```

I can't call through the website [netlifylink/test/1]. It's "Page Not Found
Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site".

But can still access localhost:8080/test/1

i call  localhost:8080/home and [netlifylink/home] is work. why?

help me please.Sorry for grammar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are special deploy instructions for SPAs on Netlify. On this page: https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/ if you go to the **History Pushstate and Single Page Apps** section you will see this:

> If you’re developing a single page app and want history pushstate to work so you get clean URLs, you’ll want to enable the following rewrite rule:
>
> /*    /index.html   200
>
> This will effectively serve the index.html instead of giving a 404 no matter what URL the browser requests.

You need to add this to the `_redirects` file under the root of your built site.

Comment: The '_redirects' goes in the root of the deployed site. I made the edit.

Comment: I'm a little confused how this fixed my 404 problem, but it did, so for that I thank you, sir.   Netlify was responding 404 when I had AWS Cognito redirect a successful user pool auth request back to a vue-router served page in my app (VueJS 2.x app running on Netlify).  I literally just added a "_redirects" file to my /public/ folder of my codebase with this line in it and it seems to work well now.

Comment: It worked for me when I added a new file called "_redirects" in my dist folder.

Answer (score 11):

It's also in the Vue documentation deployment section

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#netlify

In order to receive direct hits using `history mode` on Vue Router, you need to create a file called `_redirects` under `/public` with the following content:

```
# Netlify settings for single-page application
/*    /index.html   200
```

Answer (score 4):

create a file called `netlify.toml` in the root of your project and then paste this:

```js
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```